# No live SolrServers available to handle this request

Tags: magento, solr

I have installed Solarium search extension in my Magento and installed solr server.

Now I try to search any word in my search box but then I am getting the following error:

> "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: No live
>   SolrServers available to handle this request"

Please help me to resolve this error.